# Find equation of tangent line using differential equation: dy/dx = x(y^1/3)

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> The expression $\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = x\sqrt[3]{y}$ gives the slope at any point on the graph of the function $f(x)$ where $f(2) = 8$.
>
> a. Write the equation of the tangent line to $f(x)$ at point $(2,8)$.

Since $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ gives the slope of the tangent line at any point, can I just plug and chug $(2,8)$ into the differential equation, and then use that slope in the point-slope formula? This would give:

$\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = (2)(\sqrt[3]{8})$

$\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = 4$

$y - 8 = 4(x - 2)\\
y = 4(x - 2) + 8$

... could anyone verify that?

> b. Write an expression for $f(x)$ in terms of $x$.

I got: $x = \sqrt{3y^\frac 23 + C}$, where $C$ is a constant of integration. Not quite sure whether this is correct or not.

> c. What is the domain of $f(x)$?

I have no idea how to begin answering this question. Could it be all real numbers, since the domain of the differential equation seems to be all real numbers?

> d. What is the minimum value of $f(x)$?

I think I have to set $\displaystyle\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = 1$, but then what? Is it $x = 0, y = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

separating the variables and integrating, we get $$\int_8^y y^{-1/3}\, dy = \int_2^x x \,dx \to \frac32\left(y^{2/3} - 4\right)=\frac12\left(x^2 - 4\right) $$ solving for $$y = f(x) = \left(\frac 13 (x^2+8)\right)^{3/2}.$$ that answers part(b).

for part (c), the domain of $f$ is all real numbers.
and for part (d), $f$ has a global minimum $f(0) = \left(\frac 83\right)^{3/2}$ at $x = 0.$

Comment: two small things: after separating x and y, we would end up with y^(-1/3), not y^(1/3) (if i'm not mistaken). Also, I can't quite get which part of the question this is answering. But thank you for helping! Oh and, could you, maybe, also verify the first two parts? thank you!!

Comment: @TheOneWhoCould, thank for spotting the typo. i have edited my answer.

Comment: if I could indulge you for just a few moments more, why do you integrate from 8 to y, and from 2 to x? To solve the differential equation (to find the solution to part b) don't we just integrate with indefinite integrals? Also, for part d, why exactly is the minimum at x = 0? Oh, it's cause x is squared, right? I think I get that last one.

Comment: Also, there is a part e, in which I have to 'sketch a slope field' at 9 points: (-1,2), (0,2), (1,2), and a couple more. Do I just plug the x,y values into the dy/dx equation to find a general idea of the slope at that point, which I could use to draw arrows at each point? thank you again!

Comment: @TheOneWhoCould, that is what you do. make sure the small lines kind of follow the  graph of the solution.